# Como imprimo el menor valor de un vector en VB

Tags: vb

buenas tardes tengo el siguiente problema, el programa esta ya todo resuelto en su mayoria, de un vector de 10 valores, muestra el vector original, el promedio, si esta reprobado o no y el numero menor, este ultimo no me refleja el valor si no un 0, me pueden auxiliar?, ya cambie a otro for, y no me arroja el menor en cambio si cambio ese signo si me da el mayor

```
    Public Class Form1
    Dim vector(10), i As Integer
    Dim Sum As Double
    Dim Prom As Double
    Dim cont As Double
    Dim min As Integer

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Label1.Text = ""
        Label2.Text = ""
        Label3.Text = ""
        Label4.Text = ""

        For i = 1 To 10
            Label1.Text = Label1.Text & vector(i) & " "
            Sum += vector(i)
            cont += 1

        Next
        Prom = Sum / cont

        For i = 1 To 10
            If min > vector(i) Then
                min = vector(i)
            End If

        Next
        If Prom > 5 Then
            Label3.Text = "Aprobado"
        Else
            Label3.Text = "reprobado"

        End If

        Label2.Text = Label2.Text & Prom & " "
        Label4.Text = Label4.Text & min & " "
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        For i = 1 To 10
            vector(i) = InputBox("Ingresa el numero del vector", "Datos Vector", 0)

        Next

    End Sub
End Class
introducir el código aquí
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que, cuando declaras la variable `min` esta, por defecto, vale 0, y por tanto la condición `If min > vector(i)` se cumpliría solo si `vector(i)` es negativo.

Lo que puedes hacer es inicializar la variable `min` a un valor lo suficientemente alto para que se asigne siempre que encuentre el primer elemento del vector. Por ejemplo, si esperas valores entre 1 y 100, podrías inicializarla con 101, por ejemplo, puedes hacer algo como esto:

```
    min = 10000 'inicializo la variable a un valor lo suficientemente alto
    For i = 1 To 10
        If min > vector(i) Then
            min = vector(i)
        End If
```

Comment: muchas gracia sme sirvio

Comment: @user214712, me alegra, puedes considerar ser un buen ciudadano siguiendo algunas de [estas recomendaciones](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Y si probas de llamar a Min dentro de la funcion en vez de en la inicializacion.

Solo asigna la variable encima de esta linea

```
min = vector.Min
Label2.Text = Label2.Text & Prom & " "
```

Comment: me sigue marcando 0 :/